# Continuously search in a text file to see if the pre-identified string is present

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python to keep search in the text file to see if the string presents and shows in order.
For example, if I would like to search name: Jill, Andy, Zara.
The input in text file has 100 names, one name in each line.

I tried to use the if keyword in line command to do the search and able to find them.
But how I can make sure they come in order?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally get this, but I'm assuming that your text file is being written to by another program and you'd like to monitor it?  I would dump it into a list every couple of minutes and check the list.

```
import time

runIt = True
while runIt:
     file = open("nameFile.txt", "r")
     listOfNames = file.read()
     file.close()
     
     if name in listOfNames:
          do something with that name
     elif <what you want to break the loop>:
          renIt = False
     
     time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I did similar thing as your answer to find out the words, but how I can make sure those words in the txt file are in certain order?

Comment: Once your names are in the list, you can manipulate them easily.  You can listOfNames.sort() to put them in alphabetical order or listOfNames.sort(reverse=True) to do the opposite.  Otherwise, they will just be in the order that they were in in the text file.

Comment: You can also dedupe the list with listOfNames = list(dict.fromkeys(listOfNames))

Answer (score 0):

try pool and parallel process your task https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/